# Unable to add package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb in Asp.net MVC 4.5 version from Nuget package manager

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created project in asp.net MVC with 4.5 framework in 2015 VS. I am trying to add Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb this package from nuget package manager but getting error like

> Could not install package 'Microsoft.Owin 4.0.0'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5',  but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework.

Even if I changed framework still getting error and

> Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb latest Version of this package is 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

f you are installing last versions of SignalR you will not be able as it has some dependencies that require .Net4.5, but you can still install an old version of SignalR which uses .Net4.0, like

> 1.1.3 Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Version 1.1.3

This is not the case any more, and the 2.x releases require .NET 4.5.

> https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1723

Comment: Thank you for the help.Now I am getting Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies dll reference in my solution.

Comment: But same error I am getting for installing "Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" this package from nuget.please help me.